# Insert Text into a Form in iFrame and click on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Alright. I basically want to create an iframe on my website which leads to my other website.

On my iFramed website I have a form with a Text Field and a Submit button. I would like to insert some text to the Text Field and then Click on the submit button WHEN I click on a button at Site A (the one which contains the iframe).

Is it possible in some way?

I have tried the follwoing but it doesn't seems to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertTxt() {
        var textstring = "test successful";
        window.frames["iframeAB"].document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = textstring;
    }
</script>

<iframe name="iframeAB" src ="index.html" id="qab" width="100%" height="210" style="border:1px solid #009ee0">
    Your browser doesn't handle iframes
</iframe>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="top.frames['iframeAB'].window.document.body.getElementById('text_field').value='test successful';"/>
<a href="#" onclick="insertTxt();">test</a>
```

Comment: Unless on same domain, port and protocol, not possible

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.frames["iframeAB"].documentContent` instead of `window.frames["iframeAB"].document`

Answer (score 0):

Try this using **jQuery**:

```
// Include the jQuery file inside the head tag
// Download the latest version, this is in the jQuery website
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
// Then call the code inside ready method like this
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get the iFrame jQuery Object
    var $MyFrame = $("iframe[name='iframeAB']");

    // You need to wait for the iFrame content to load first
    // So, that the click events work properly
    $MyFrame.load(function () {
        var frameBody = $MyFrame.contents().find('body');

        // Find the textarea by id
        var textarea = frameBody.find('#text_field');

        // Set the value here...
        textarea.val(textstring);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: I'm not so good with jQuery. Can you please tell me how can I call this function? Or I should just paste this code to the head between Javascript tags and it will work?

Comment: It should work even for other domain? I mean Site A is on my domain and Site B (the iFramed one) in another domain. Would that work in that case?

Comment: It doesn't seems to work at all :( I have tired this by creating an Index file and create a file which contains the form itself, but it doesn't seens to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this solution:

It uses JQuery

**Your HTML**

```
<iframe name="iframeAB" src ="index.html" id="qab" width="100%" height="210" style="border:1px solid #009ee0">
    Your browser doesn't handle iframes
</iframe>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="top.frames['iframeAB'].window.document.body.getElementById('text_field').value='test successful';"/>
<a href="#" onclick="insertTxt();">test</a>
```

**insertTxt() method in JS file**

```
$("#qab").ready(function() {
    $("#qab").contents().find("body").find('textarea').val('Test Successful');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, try know

```
<script>
    let preFillForm = () => {

        //name attribute of iframe in box bracket
        let iframe = window.frames["myiframe"].document

        iframe.getElementById("email").value = 'kdbagwe007@gmail.com'
        iframe.getElementById("password").value = 'kdbagwe007'

        //click button after 4 seconds of iframe load or whenever u want
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('click')
            iframe.getElementById("submit").click();
        }, 4000);
    }
</script>

<iframe name="myiframe" width="600px" height="400px" src="your-url"
    onload="preFillForm()"
>
</iframe>
```